# When are kernels isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring,  $I$, $J$, two ideals in $R$ with $J \subset I \subset R$.

Suppose as quotient rings,  $R/I$ is isomorphic to
$(R/J) /  (I/J)$.

---

Are there any conditions for which the two ideals $J$ and $I/J$ can be claimed to be isomorphic?

Comment: Ehr...under your conditions, $R/I$ is *always* isomorphic to $(R/J)/(I/J)$. This is one of the isomorphism theorems. No, you can't say anything about $J$ and $I/J$.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arturo Magidin pointed out, for any commutative ring $R$ and ideals $I$, $J$ with $J \subset I \subset R$ we have

$$ R/I \simeq (R/J)/(I/J) $$

by the [third isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2) (5th remark). So there is really nothing that can be deduced from $R/I \simeq (R/J)/(I/J)$.